# Problem importing europarl module/data-set to python

Tags: python, tensorflow

so i was watching this video on how to make a translator using tensorflow and there seems to be no solution on how to import this module named europarl, does this happen due to europarl being a data set? if so how can I import it? This is the video link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vI2Y3I-JI2Q&t=483s
I'm also pretty new to this and want to learn how to create neural networks that can translate text and summarize them so if you guys have any suggestions please comment it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [github repository](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials) with Tensorflow Tutorials (including Machine Translation tutorial). This repository contains all dependent files (including europarl.py). You can clone this repository by using `git clone https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials.git` or download files by [link](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/archive/master.zip).